# How to restore node combinations?

Tags: node-editor

I have this spiral with 5 slots.

Now I'm going to try color combinations for each slot e.g. black as color for slot *ground* and any other for topLeft. I then render, save the png image and make other changes.

After doing a dozen or more, how can I save these settings?

[image: pic]

Comment: Hello, if all you're changing is the color you should look into cryptomatte or object index pass, that way you can change the color in the compositor any way you want and you don't have to render it again